# pygame object wont move

Tags: python, pygame

I have a very simple program. What I want is items in the thing class to move on their own.

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import threading
#initilasies it
pygame.init()
#variables for height and width
global display_width
display_width= 800
global display_height
display_height= 600

#declares colours uses RGB as reference
white= (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

#sets the dispaly (must be inside a tuple ())
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
#changes the name of the window
pygame.display.set_caption("Robot Quest")
#times stuff (is gonna be used for FPS)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#loads up an image (not shown) must be in same directory
tankImg = pygame.image.load("tank.png")
blockImg = pygame.image.load("block.png")

class things:
    def __init__(self,width,height,speed):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        #if display.width doesn't work just pass the screen dimensions
        self.X = display_width - self.width
        self.Y= display_height - self.height
        self.speed = speed


    def move(self):
        self.X -= self.speed
        pos = self.X
        return pos

    def drawImage(self,imageName,x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(imageName,(x,y))

def game_loop():

    #game exit value is set
    game_exit = False

    #when true you exit the loop, logic goes here
    while not game_exit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #method below on what to do if they press x in the corner
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #exit the loop
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        #fills the background
        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        block = things(100,100,4)
        block.drawImage(blockImg,block.X,block.Y)
        block.move()

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(30)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

In the program block.move() executes once but that's all, so the object stays in the same place, having shifted only once place. I've tried to put the block.move() function in a for and while loop, but the program doesn't run if I do so. Can anyone advise me how fix my code so the object moves continuously, so it moves from end to the screen to another?

Comment: You seem to initialize your block in each loop. Try moving `block = things(100,100,4)`to before the while loop.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. :D

Comment: @Moberg post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: Your turn @KungFuHustled. Please accept Moberg's answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to initialize your block in each loop. Try moving `block = things(100,100,4)` to before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're re-initializing your block inside of your while loop, so in each iteration you're resetting it to its original position then moving it. Try moving the initialization outside of the while loop:

```
def game_loop():

    #game exit value is set
    game_exit = False

    block = things(100,100,4)

    #when true you exit the loop, logic goes here
    while not game_exit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #method below on what to do if they press x in the corner
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #exit the loop
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        #fills the background
        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        block.drawImage(blockImg,block.X,block.Y)
        block.move()

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(30)
```